# Multiple db connections in Yii PHP framework

Tags: php, yii

This is the main.php file:

```
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=MYHOST;dbname=MYDB',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'MYUSER',
            'password' => 'MYPASS',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'dbanother' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=MYHOST;dbname=MYDB2',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'MYUSER2',
            'password' => 'MYPASS2',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'
        ),
```

In the UserIdentity from components I have this:

```
 public function authenticate() {
    .........
    $loggedInUser = User::model()->find("username = :username", array("username" => $this->username));
    ......
 }
```

and in the **User** model , where i want to use the table users from the MYDB2 database:

```
    class User extends CActiveRecord {

        private $connection_db2;

        /**
         * @see db connections from config/main.php
         */
        public function __construct(){
            $this->connection_db2= Yii::app()->dbanother;
        }

        public static function model($className=__CLASS__){
            return parent::model($className);
        }

        public function tableName() {
            return Yii::app()->dbanother->users;
            // here i want to declare That i want to use the table **users**
        }
    .....
    }
```

At the moment I am getting this:

> Property "CDbConnection.users" is not defined.

**Can you help me with this ? thx**

Comment: What file, line and code where this error occur? (in error page print `$file` and `$line` variables, also stack is in `$trace`

Comment: protected\models\User.php(36): CComponent->__get('users')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's even simpler :) Just override the `getDbConnection()` method in your class:

```
public function getDbConnection() {
    return Yii::app()->dbanother;
}
```

Comment: well, now I am getting this: Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class CActiveRecord in C:\xampp\htdocs\YII\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php on line 395

Comment: Can you help me with this :D ?

Comment: Try removing the `__construct` function from your class. It's no longer needed now, and since you're not calling `parent::__construct()` from within, it could cause problems like this.

Comment: In my class user I have just 2 function: public function getDbConnection() {
     return Yii::app()->dbanother;
 }
    public function tableName() {
        return 'users';
    }

Comment: and I am getting the error that I mentioned earlier

Comment: Ah, you do still need the `model` function in each class in Yii1. Try putting that one back.

Comment: I put this back :public static function model($className=__CLASS__){
     return parent::model($className);
   }    and it works, THX